# Can there be data loss when streaming into bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, streaming

I'm currently pushing some data into a table in bigquery, and I can see missing data in last 2 days, however I can I can see in logs HTTP 200. Is there any chance data could end up missing from BQ streaming buffer?

Answer (score 3):

Are you inspecting the full response for tabledata.insertAll beyond the HTTP response code?  Streaming may return http 200 responses but include additional information about specific rows with issues in the request batch: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#streaming-success